# Angular Service dependency injection on same component from different routes

Tags: angular

I have two modules with as below. I want to share the component from the first module in the second module but with a parameters to indicate which module its coming from. How can I do that using a service?

First module

```
@NgModule( {
declarations: [
    MasterListComponent
              ]
```

In the second module I can easily use the component as below

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'list'
}, {
    path: 'list',
    data: { title: 'Administration' },
    component: MasterListComponent
}];
```

But in the MasterListComponent constructor, how can I inject a service to know where is component has been invoked from?

Comment: Why don't you use `data` property as you already did ? `data: { module: "NAME_OF_YOUR_MODULE" }`

Comment: How do you use data property in the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a property directly into your module like this :

```js
{
    path: 'list',
    data: {
      title: 'Administration',
      module: 'Your module',
    },
    component: MasterListComponent
}
```

Then in your component just do this :

```js
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log(this.route.snapshot.data.module);
}
```